# Crash in NSManagedObjectContext+MagicalSaves.m line 83

Tags: crash, save, magicalrecord

I have a crash in Crashlytics in line 83 of `NSManagedObjectContext+MagicalSaves.m` (just sporadically, but 2% of my users have it, being called form different corners. I am wondering why the try catch of `MagicalRecord` does not help. Here is more insight of the crash:

```
12 CoreData                       0x0000000187f1a354 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 176
13 CoreData                       0x0000000187e9d400 -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 1284
14 Schlaukopf                     0x000000010000c18c __70-[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:]_block_invoke15 (NSManagedObjectContext+MagicalSaves.m:83)
15 CoreData                       0x0000000187f11270 developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 200
16 CoreData                       0x0000000187f11474 -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 232
17 "myApp"                     0x000000010000bfc8 -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:] (NSManagedObjectContext+MagicalSaves.m:129)
```

Does anybody have a glue what to consider, how to solve?